# .htaccess Merge 2 rules into one

Tags: .htaccess

I want to merge 2 rules into 1. I want to make sure cause this change will affect around 40 rules.

These are my 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^award/(\d+)/?$ admin.php?io=award&award=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^award/add/?$ admin.php?io=award[L]
```

Can i merge them like this:

```
RewriteRule ^award/add|(\d+)/?$ admin.php?io=award&award=$1 [L]
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^award/(?:add|(\d+))/?$ admin.php?io=award&award=$1 [L]
```

With an empty parameter `award` for `award/add`.

Or:

```
RewriteRule ^award/(add|\d+)/?$ admin.php?io=award&award=$1 [L]
```

With `award=add` for `award/add`.